# Scrollbar of webview not working

Tags: imageview, javafx-8, scenebuilder

[image]

Before inserting the imageview, the webview was perfectly working! But after inserting imageview the webview shows but cant scroll!

It is mentioning that, the imageview is just for the first front page. I mean when Button will clicked then the image will disappear. I handle this code inside the buttonhandle by this way-

```
img.setImage(null);
System.gc();
```

My fxml file-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Menu?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.web.WebView?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" fx:id="anc" prefHeight="560.0" prefWidth="784.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="Controller.WebController">
   <children>
      <TextField fx:id="txt" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="33.0" onAction="#txtHandle" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="625.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="3.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="145.0" />
      <Button fx:id="bt" layoutX="702.0" layoutY="33.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handle" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="68.0" text="Go" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="14.0" />
      <MenuBar fx:id="menubar" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefWidth="784.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="14.0">
        <menus>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Menu">
            <items>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="History" />
                  <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Close" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
            <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Option">
              <items>
                <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#blockHandle" text="Block Site" />
                  <MenuItem fx:id="viewBlock" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#viewBlockHandle" text="View Blocked Websites" />
              </items>
            </Menu>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Edit">
            <items>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Delete" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Help">
            <items>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#aboutHandle" text="About Us" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
        </menus>
      </MenuBar>
      <WebView fx:id="webView" prefHeight="495.0" prefWidth="784.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="65.0" />
      <VBox alignment="CENTER" layoutX="244.0" layoutY="168.0" prefHeight="344.0" prefWidth="458.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="65.0">
         <children>
            <ImageView fx:id="img" fitHeight="288.0" fitWidth="394.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
               <image>
                  <Image url="@../Image/logo.png" />
               </image>
            </ImageView>
         </children>
      </VBox>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: Probably the `ImageView` is causing the `VBox` to grow so that it overlaps the `WebView`, resulting in mouse events being sent to the `VBox` instead of the `WebView`. It's impossible to know for sure without a [MCVE]. You may want to use a layout pane that properly manages the controls in the way you want.

Comment: I edited my post and add the xml file. Can you please say how to solve this problem?

Comment: I recommend using ScenicView found here  - http://fxexperience.com/scenic-view/ which will allow you too see the layout of the objects at runtime and see if something is overlapping something else.  I had this issue where something during runtime expanded just enough to overlay the title pane arrow preventing it from being clicked.  ScenicView allowed me to see the boundaries while running.

Comment: Well you are clearly placing the `VBox` on top of the `WebView`. Just arrange them so they don't overlap. (Only you actually know how you want the layout to happen, no-one else can really know what you want here.) Again, I recommend using a [layout pane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/layout-tutorial/builtin_layouts.htm#JFXLY102) instead of using `AnchorPane`s and hard-coding all the layout coordinates. If you really want the image to overlap the web view, make it mouse-transparent with `mouseTransparent="true"`.